# The modes of encryption that preserve the format

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, format-preserving

Can anyone give me some documentation on the various format preserving encryption modes?

Comment: Did you not find anything satisfying from your favorite search engine? Did you check out NIST-SP-800-38* series? Why did you believe [sha-256] tag is relevant here?

Comment: I found my problem, thank you for giving me more information, that's great, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm aware of only one official specification: [NIST SP 800-38G](https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.SP.800-38G), and recommend to ignore it. Rather, consider [NIST SP 800-38Gr1-draft](https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.SP.800-38Gr1-draft), still unofficial, *if* something next to a rubber stamp is badly needed.

That draft changes both modes in the official specification, FF1 and FF3, fixing security issues:

- The minimal size of the input/output space is increased from a hundred to a million elements (e.g. from two to six decimal digits).
- FF3 is changed to FF3-1 with reduced tweak space, following F. Betül Durak and Serge Vaudenay's [*Breaking the FF3 Format-Preserving Encryption Standard over Small Domains*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/521.pdf), in [proceedings of Crypto 2017](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-63715-0_23).

Note: the NSA reported that FF2 aka VAES3 of [NIST SP 800-38G-draft](https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.SP.800-38Gdraft.pdf) has less than 128-bit security, [NIST confirmed that](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/306) and withdrew it.

Comment: Great, your information was very helpful to me, thank you very much!